# Mysql search all column together with WHERE and LIKE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database where in the table there is four column `id,title,address,phone`.When searched with a selected table the query search the term in that particular row and result is fetched,but what I want to know is if no table is selected that is i.e-

```
   <option value="">Select table</option>
```

I want the query to search the term in every table,I could do it with `WHERE row1 LIKE %$keyword% OR row2 LIKE %$keyword%`,but I want it to search this thing in one query as if it select all row data and search it with the term,like first it search the `row 1` then `row2`  the `row3` one after another on its own.Is there any way to do it

```
   <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  { 
   $keyword= $_POST['keyword'];
   $table= $_POST['table'];

    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

   $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information WHERE $table LIKE '%".$keyword."%'");  

   //And we display the results 
   while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
   { 
   echo $result['id'];
   echo $result['title']; 
   }
   }
   ?>
   <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='POST'>
   <input type='text' size='90' name='keyword'>
   <select name='table'>
   <option value="">Select table</option>
   <option value="title">title</option>
   <option value="address">address</option>
   <option value="phone">phone</option>
   </select>
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' >
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you have should work, but you also need to concatenate the where clause. Try this one.

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information WHERE `{$table}` LIKE '%".$keyword."%'");

Comment: ,it works when anyone selects a vlaue for the $table what i asked is if anyone doesn't select anything that is there is no valuei.e-if some one does not select and let it be <option value="">Select table</option>,what will be the sql for the query to search all the rows of the table as no rows is selected ?

Comment: Well, then you should check whether the table variable is set or not. If not, return an error.

Comment: I want it to be like this that if no row is selected it will search all the rows together

Comment: I think you've got _table_, _rows_, and _columns_ mixed up. You know, in your example `information` is the table, where `$table` is your **column**. So in your dropdown, use the text `Select column`, and the query would look like `"SELECT * FROM \`information\` WHERE \`{$column}\` LIKE '%".$keyword."%'"`. Now, to search all columns, you would have to use [Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or iterate through your fields using `DESCRIBE information`.

Comment: Will CONCAT() do the job ?

Comment: CONCAT() does the job perfectly